# With some shared parameters, and some not, what are my degrees of freedom?

Tags: nonlinear-regression, degrees-of-freedom, parameterization

I have a data matrix $X$ of size $m \times (n+1)$ where there are $n$ dependent variables and one independent variable $t$. I also have a collection of $n$ nonlinear functions $f_1, \cdots, f_j, \cdots, f_n$ predicting those first $n$ column variables with the $n+1$ column, representing time $t$. Each function has a collection of parameters $\theta_{1, j}, \cdots, \theta_{{h_j}, j}$ that are not shared across other functions, and a collection of shared parameters $\gamma_1, \cdots, \gamma_p$ across all aforementioned functions.

Thus a given regression equation would look like:

$$X_j = f_j \left(t; \theta_{1, j}, \cdots, \theta_{{h_j}, j}, \gamma_1, \cdots, \gamma_p \right)$$

I will be simultaneously parameterizing the models, but I am unsure how to calculate the degrees of freedom. It would seem that the parameters $\theta_{1, j}, \cdots, \theta_{{h_j}, j}$ would contribute $n\left(m - \sum_{j=1}^n {h_j}\right)$ degrees of freedom while the shared parameters $\gamma_1, \cdots, \gamma_p$ would contribute $mn - p$ degrees of freedom. But when I consider how to combine them it occurs to me that their sum may be double counting sample entries. One possibility is $mn - \sum_{j=1}^n {h_j} - p$ that uses the notion of sample size minus the number of parameters, but I am unsure if this is appropriate here.

How should I calculate the degrees of freedom for this parametrization?

Comment: What do you plan to do with these degrees of freedom once you compute them?  It's necessary to ask because "degrees of freedom" has at least three possible distinct meanings in this context and can give rise to three different numerical answers.

Comment: @whuber That is very interesting to me. Would you point me to a source that describes these three distinct meanings, or briefly describe them?

I wish to avoid overspecification.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16921/how-to-understand-degrees-of-freedom

Comment: What are these three meanings to "degrees of freedom"?

Comment: See the top hits on this site related to [degrees of freedom](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22degrees%20of%20freedom%22).

Comment: @whuber I've read [your answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16921/how-to-understand-degrees-of-freedom) that states "Accordingly, it cannot be the case that DF is adequately explainable in terms of the geometry of multivariate normal distributions, or in terms of functional independence, or as counts of parameters, or anything else of this nature.". That speaks to what DF is not, rather than what it is.

Comment: I felt (and continue to feel) that was an appropriate summary of a post that is part of a thread in which all those meanings are amply described: indeed, I came up with that list by referring to the other answers in the thread.

Comment: See [Ye 1998](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2669609) for a generalization of degrees of freedom.